# Позиция не правильная html или css

Tags: html

всем привет сделал форму и таблицу  теперь не могу разобраться:

1. как в форме поставить позицию для каждого input`a и label`ы, чтобы они
   были не в ряд вниз, а рядом по середине и так далее;
2. позиция таблицы не совпадает с позицией формы ввода данных ну как в одной линией;

собственно код и сама страничка :

```html
<?php
 include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/Work_Log/main.php');
 include('\Work_Log\include\content.php');
 {
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Work_Log - Журнал регистрации поступивших в архив дел</title>
  <?php getHead(); ?>
</head>

<head>
  <div class='content'>
    <h3>Регистрации поступивших в архив дел</h3>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <div class='block' style=' max-height:500px; overflow-y:scroll' ;>
</head>
<form method="post" action='action/?method=addjournal1'>
  <span class="label"> Дата поступления </span>
  <input style="width: 10%;" type="date" class="input" name="date_start">
  <span class="label"> Наименование дел </span>
  <input style="width: 10%;" type="text" class="input" name="named">
  <span class="label"> Номер по архиву </span>
  <input style="width: 10%;" type="text" class="input" name="narchive">
  <span class="label"> Номер по номенклатуре дел </span>
  <input style="width: 10%;" type="text" class="input" name="nomenkl">
  <span class="label"> Количество листов в описи </span>
  <input style="width: 10%;" type="text" class="input" name="sopis">
  <span class="label"> Количество листов в деле </span>
  <input style="width: 10%;" type="text" class="input" name="scase">
  <span class="label">Срок окончание хранения </span>
  <input style="width: 10%;" type="date" class="input" name="date_end">
  <span class="label">Подписи принимающего</span>
  <input style="width: 15%;" class="input" name="rsign">
  <span class="label">Подписи сдающего </span>
  <input style="width: 15%;" class="input" name="rover">
  <span class="label">Отметка об уничтожении </span>
  <input style="width: 15%;" class="input" name="destroy">
  <br/>
  <br /><input type="submit" name="add" value="Добавить" /><br />
  <br />
</form>
</div>

<body>
  <div class=log>
    <?php getlog(); ?>
  </div>
  <?php getMenu(); ?>
  <html>

  </html>
  <div class='content'>
    <h1>Журнал регистрации поступивших в архив дел</h1>
    <div class='block' style=' max-height:500px; overflow-y:scroll' ;>
      <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10" width="100%">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td rowspan="2"><b> №п\п </b></td>
            <td rowspan="2"><b> Дата поступление в архив </b></td>
            <td rowspan="2"><b> Наименование дел </b></td>
            <td colspan="2"><b> Номер </b></td>
            <td colspan="2"><b> Количество листов </b></td>
            <td rowspan="2"><b> Срок окончания хранения </b></td>
            <td colspan="2"><b> Подписи ответственных лиц </b></td>
            <td rowspan="2"><b> Отметка об уничтожении </b></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><b>по архиву</b></td>
            <td><b>по номенклатуре дел</b></td>
            <td><b>в описи</b></td>
            <td><b>в деле</b></td>
            <td><b>принимающего </b></td>
            <td><b>сдающего</b></td>
          </tr>
          <?php  
 getConect();
 mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
 $i=1;
 $query = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `journal1`');
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query) )
 {
  echo "<tr><td>".$i."</td>";
  echo "<td>".$row['date_start']."</td>";
  echo "<td>".$row['named']."</td>";
  echo "<td>".$row['narchive']."</td>";
  echo "<td>".$row['nomenkl']."</td>";
  echo "<td>".$row['sopis']."</td>";
  echo "<td>".$row['scase']."</td>";
  echo "<td>".$row['date_end']."</td>";
  echo "<td>".$row['rsign']."</td>";
  echo "<td>".$row['rover']."</td>";
  echo "<td>".$row['destroy']."</td></tr>";
  $i++;
 }
 ?>

        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>

<?php
 }
 ?>
```

простите если код ужасный я новичок

Comment: Может лутше `span` i `input` обернуть в `div class` и уже работать с классом, выстраивать как надо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  display: block;
```

Если я правильно понял их картинки, или вы хотите чтобы выглядела как таблица?

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box
}

input {
  display: block;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table input{
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  padding: 2px;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.no-padding td{
  padding: 0
}
```

```html
<form method="post" action='action/?method=addjournal1'>
  <span class="label"> Дата поступления </span>
  <input type="date" class="input" name="date_start">
  <span class="label"> Наименование дел </span>
  <input type="text" class="input" name="named">
  <span class="label"> Номер по архиву </span>
  <input type="text" class="input" name="narchive">
  <span class="label"> Номер по номенклатуре дел </span>
  <input type="text" class="input" name="nomenkl">
  <span class="label"> Количество листов в описи </span>
  <input type="text" class="input" name="sopis">
  <span class="label"> Количество листов в деле </span>
  <input type="text" class="input" name="scase">
  <span class="label">Срок окончание хранения </span>
  <input type="date" class="input" name="date_end">
  <span class="label">Подписи принимающего</span>
  <input class="input" name="rsign">
  <span class="label">Подписи сдающего </span>
  <input class="input" name="rover">
  <span class="label">Отметка об уничтожении </span>
  <input class="input" name="destroy">
  <br/>
  <br /><input type="submit" name="add" value="Добавить" />
</form>
</div>
<hr>

<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10" width="100%">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2"><b> №п\п </b></td>
      <td rowspan="2"><b> Дата поступление в архив </b></td>
      <td rowspan="2"><b> Наименование дел </b></td>
      <td colspan="2"><b> Номер </b></td>
      <td colspan="2"><b> Количество листов </b></td>
      <td rowspan="2"><b> Срок окончания хранения </b></td>
      <td colspan="2"><b> Подписи ответственных лиц </b></td>
      <td rowspan="2"><b> Отметка об уничтожении </b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><b>по архиву</b></td>
      <td><b>по номенклатуре дел</b></td>
      <td><b>в описи</b></td>
      <td><b>в деле</b></td>
      <td><b>принимающего </b></td>
      <td><b>сдающего</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="no-padding">
      <td></td>
      <td><input/></td>
      <td><input/></td>
      <td><input/></td>
      <td><input/></td>
      <td><input/></td>
      <td><input/></td>
      <td><input/></td>
      <td><input/></td>
      <td><input/></td>
      <td><input/></td>
</tr>
</table>
<hr>

<body>
  <div class=log>
    <?php getlog(); ?>
  </div>
  <?php getMenu(); ?>
  <html>

  </html>
  <div class='content'>
    <h1>Журнал регистрации поступивших в архив дел</h1>
    <div class='block'>
      <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10" width="100%">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td rowspan="2"><b> №п\п </b></td>
            <td rowspan="2"><b> Дата поступление в архив </b></td>
            <td rowspan="2"><b> Наименование дел </b></td>
            <td colspan="2"><b> Номер </b></td>
            <td colspan="2"><b> Количество листов </b></td>
            <td rowspan="2"><b> Срок окончания хранения </b></td>
            <td colspan="2"><b> Подписи ответственных лиц </b></td>
            <td rowspan="2"><b> Отметка об уничтожении </b></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><b>по архиву</b></td>
            <td><b>по номенклатуре дел</b></td>
            <td><b>в описи</b></td>
            <td><b>в деле</b></td>
            <td><b>принимающего </b></td>
            <td><b>сдающего</b></td>
          </tr>
          <?php  
 getConect();
 mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
 $i=1;
 $query = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `journal1`');
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query) )
 {
  echo "<tr><td>".$i."</td>";
  echo "<td>".$row['date_start']."</td>";
  echo "<td>".$row['named']."</td>";
  echo "<td>".$row['narchive']."</td>";
  echo "<td>".$row['nomenkl']."</td>";
  echo "<td>".$row['sopis']."</td>";
  echo "<td>".$row['scase']."</td>";
  echo "<td>".$row['date_end']."</td>";
  echo "<td>".$row['rsign']."</td>";
  echo "<td>".$row['rover']."</td>";
  echo "<td>".$row['destroy']."</td></tr>";
  $i++;
 }
 ?>

        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>

<?php
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: нет чет я не понял вас,  форма остается такой же но расположение (позиций )ввода данных в форме должны быть разные это возможно, а внизу таблица должна в линиию не чуть в право как она на картинке а наобарот по центру как форма ввода

Comment: Не понимаю, как журнал?  должен быть вид

Comment: нет кароче,есть форма регистраций и форма журнала в виде таблицы стоит вот на картинке форма регистраций сверху это с кнопкой добавить не должна вообще пролистоваться вниз а как бы все в ряд по горизонтали не все имеется ввиду там несколько , потом добавить, и все а журнал просто выровнить надо чуть влево

Comment: Не понимаю, вряд колонка ))) Что именно хотите не понять.  Подправил пример, там несколько вариантов, в том числе пример форму в виде таблицы. Нужно только обернуть формой и добавить кнопку отправки